# what is tabular dataformat in java and how i can save tabular data format in to a string array list?

Tags: java, mbeans

Hi when you have a look at MBeans classes you will come to know few classes also return data in tabular data format of java. Can anyone let me know what is this and how i can save tabular data format in to a string array list.

[Java Doc Link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/management/openmbean/TabularDataSupport.html)

Comment: TabularDataSupport, i m taliking about this class... plz find link of javadoc in question.

Comment: by "string array list" do you mean `ArrayList<String>` or `List<String[]>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert the `TabularData`  to a list of strings containing the values of each row in the table, you can use something like this.

(Note that `TabularData` is an interface - `TabularDataSupport` is one implementation. MBeans may use their own implementation, so it's best to code to the interface rather than the implementation class.)

```
String SEPARATOR = " ";  // change this as needed, e.g. to tab, comma etc.
TabularData data = ...; // data from the mbean
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  // the output list
for (Object v: data.values()) {
   CompositeData row = (CompositeData)v;
   StringBuilder rowString = new StringBuilder();
   for (Object rv: row.values()) {
       if (rowString.length()!=0)
            rowString.append(SEPARATOR);
       rowString.append(rv);
   }
   list.add(rowString.toString());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try returning `List<List<Object>>`.
Each element of the outer List is a "row".
Each element of the inner Lists is a "column" of the "row".

Comment: this approach could have been usefull when i m taking data one by one and want to save as table(logical table), but when it comes to jms you have a data type like table know as TabularDataSupport datatype... i have added link above...